# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when upload large file nodejs multer

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer, connection-reset

I'm writing an web application that allow user to upload very large file (up to GB). My technical stack include: nodejs, express, multer and pure html. It works fine for small file. But when I upload big file (127 MB), I got error **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** after waiting a while (about **2 minutes**).

I tried extended response time on server, using both req.setTimeout and res.setTimeout but it didn't help. It's may be because frontend waiting to long to get response.

Below is the error I got:

[image]

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the `res`-timeout for the corresponding upload-route should definitely work. Try doing it like this:

```
function extendTimeout (req, res, next) {
  // adjust the value for the timeout, here it's set to 3 minutes
  res.setTimeout(180000, () => { // you can handle the timeout error here })
  next();
})

app.post('/your-upload-route', extendTimeout, upload.single('your-file'), (req, res, next) => {
  // handle file upload
})
```

Comment: I already tried res.setTimeout and req.setTimeout, but it not worked. I think frontend want to hear some response in short time, not wait ultil file is uploaded.

Comment: Have you tried it like this? If yes, you probably need to adjust the request-timeout in the client.

Comment: I tried using axios at frontend but it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you add your code and show how you set the timeout in node and on the client-side?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to debug this I finally got a working solution:

The key was to bump up the values for `server.requestTimeout` AND `server.headersTimeout`

[Docs on server.headersTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_headerstimeout):

> The minimum between `server.requestTimeout` or 60000.